# I'm a celeb get me outta here: optimal strategy to open locks

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Suppose there are two 4 digit locks and a given and finite set $A$ of 4 digit tuples. Two elements of $A$ open the locks. What shall I do? Stick to the number or stick to the lock?

I. Choose the first element of $A$ and try the locks, then choose the second element of $A$ and try the locks and so forth until both are open.

II. Choose the first lock and try the elements of $A$ until open and then try the remaining elements of $A$ for the second lock.

Edit: The two 4 digit tuples that open the respective locks are distinct. One cannot try to open the locks simultaneously. A strategy is called optimal if it minimizes the attempts to open both locks.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Provide two distinct strategies. I wouldn' t know how to prove that one is optimal. I suppose that it also depends on the cardinality of $A$. Just saw the show and was wondering how to approach the problem.

Comment: Please clarify *"Two elements of A open the locks."*. Are there *precisely* two *distinct* elements of $A$ that open the locks? Do they both open both locks, or one each?

Comment: The two 4 digit tuples that open the locks are distinct and one tuple belongs to one lock each.

Comment: OK great. Next; what do you mean by optimal?

Comment: Can you edit your clarifications into the questuon? That should help it avoid being put on hold as unclear.

Comment: Also (not being a watcher of the show), can both locks be attacked at once by using two people?

Comment: Supposing you care about the number of attempted unlockings of the locks, the expected value of both strategies will be the same. So are the worst case scenarios of both